# Is an LLC Membership Certificate Legally Binding?

Tags: shareholders, limited-liability-company, equity, delaware

I'm wondering if an LLC Membership Certificate that has been signed by the owner of the company and promises a certain amount of stake in the LLC is legally binding/would hold up in court if there was ever a dispute.
There is no letter of intent.

Thanks

Comment: A certificate sounds like a formal record of ownership. That does not sound like a promise. Is it a promise to do something or is the grant something that has already happened? And LLCs have members, they dot not generally have shares.

Comment: Yes I thought the same. The certificate was signed and all was well, but it was recently discovered that the owner of the LLC had secretly kept it a single-member LLC the whole time (rather than converting to multi-member). So if any issues were to arise/this was taken to the courts, the LLC certificate would be my primary piece of evidence.

Comment: It sounds like the certificate is evidence of fraud, but the impact it would have on the membership of the LLC could depend on state law where the LLC is organized.  Which state is that?

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's in New York.

Comment: edit: just realized technically the LLC is actually based out of Delaware (not New York).